# How to find match selectors class and data attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there way to get true when match both selectors class and data attribute ?

Find matched dropdown e.g:

```
`<select class="type-featured" data-featured="normal">`
....
`<select class="type-featured" data-featured="classical">`
....
`<select class="type-featured" data-featured="modern">`
```

Find select, class equal to type-featured AND data-featured value equal to normal - here is code:

```
$('.style-wrapper').each( function() {
    var $styles = $(this);
    if ( $styles.parents().find('select').is('.type-featured, [data-featured=normal]') ) {
    // do something here
    }
});
```

I got TRUE whether select has `type-featured` class OR `data-featured="normal",  data-featured="classical",  data-featured="modern"`

Its seems to be TRUE if match any one selector.

Is possible to get my desired result using .is function? May be using anonymous function like :

```
.is( function() {
//here some logic to result
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If you deploy the jQuery:

```
$('select.type-featured[data-featured="normal"]').each(function(){

    // [... DO SOMETHING...]

});
```

you will run the function on only those `<select>` elements which have:

- `class="type-featured"`
- `data-featured="normal"`

Comment: I write this example code. My original code is big and difficult to explain. May I not explain well. Okay, if we have select, input and textarea then how to match?

Comment: Using a comma, you can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. See: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ **eg.** `$('select.type-featured[data-featured="normal"], input.type-featured[data-featured="normal"], textarea.type-featured[data-featured="normal"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `is(...)` try with `hasClass()` - this determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

Comment: The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element. Here is class and data attribue